# I can't write the "ー" katakana character in Latex

Tags: overleaf, japanese

I'm using the xeCJK package to write japanese Katakana characters, it works fine so far, except for the "ー" character (For example: "デスノート", Death Note).

Please tell me how I can fix that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be a keyboard config problem. Can you type this character directly from the keyboard in other applications?

Comment: show a small complete document that shows th problm and show the error or warning from the log for your test file.

Comment: I actually directly copied the character from another website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\begin{document}

デスノート

\end{document}
```

shows the warnings

```
Package xeCJK Warning: Fandol is being set as the default font for CJK text.
(xeCJK)                Please make sure it has been properly installed.


Package fontspec Warning: Font "FandolSong-Regular" does not contain requested
(fontspec)                Script "CJK".

Missing character: There is no ー (U+30FC) in font [FandolSong-Regular.otf]/OT:language=dflt;!
```

[image]

You need to select a font that has the character (as far as I can see it's not really used in Japanese orthography).

Using a font available in TeX Live:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setCJKmainfont{ipaexm.ttf}

\begin{document}

デスノート

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The availability of characters depends entirely on the fonts you are using, about which you gave no information.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

デスノート

\end{document}
```

Produces Warnings

```
Missing character: There is no デ (U+30C7) in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=t
ex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ス (U+30B9) in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=t
ex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ノ (U+30CE) in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=t
ex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ー (U+30FC) in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=t
ex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ト (U+30C8) in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=t
ex-text;!
```

and missing characters in the output.

Conversely

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans CJK JP}
\begin{document}

デスノート

\end{document}
```

Produces no warnings and output

[image]

Comment: You said : "about which you gave no information". You might need to read about stackexchange/stackoverflow politeness guidelines towards non experienced users asking questions, or maybe just about politeness and courtesy in general. If I could give the missing information, I would'nt need to ask the question in the first place.

Comment: @Platus no sorry you could/should have provided an example document with a missing character. You clearly had such a document as you asked the question. I did not ask for anything that you could not provide.

Comment: Next time I ask a question, just don't answer, it would be perfect!

Comment: @Platus honestly I can not see anything in this answer to which you could object. I simply stated the fact that you had provided no example so had not shown which font you were using. My example used lucida modern which has none of these characters, You were clearly using a font that had some of them. Either way the suggestion here of using Noto Sans CJK JP would solve your problem (just as ipaexm suggested by egreg solves it)

Comment: Alright, sorry.